# OpenSSH host-matching rules not honored in paramiko

Tags: python, linux, paramiko, openssh

I read [this](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/config.py#L157), says '**with more specific hostmasks taking precedence**', but when I tried, the output is not what the documentation says:

```
>>> from paramiko.config import SSHConfig
>>> ssh_config = SSHConfig()
>>> ssh_config.parse(open('/tmp/ssh_config'))
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(ssh_config._config)
[{'config': {}, 'host': ['*']},
 {'config': {'port': '22'}, 'host': ['*']},
 {'config': {'port': '23'}, 'host': ['*.example.com']}]
>>> ssh_config.lookup('ssh.example.com')
{'hostname': 'ssh.example.com', 'port': '22'}
```

In the example above, the port for ssh.example.com should be 23(the more specific one i.e. *.example.com, not *). Any one to clear out this for me? Thanks.
I read through the code, but found nothing dealing with this kind of precedence.

Comment: Perhaps you'd better raise an issue at https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues

Comment: I have sent the pull request, [#261](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/261).